# Find and replace function for similar phrases

Tags: replace, ms-word, find

I have a word doc that’s contains multiple pages of information all listed in a certain format.  At the beginning and ends of each separate event/account, there is the following sentence

```
=== end ac274747-274f-4dc2-sxd7-8j86v5g7xhxh ===
```

The characters in between the ===‘s changes after every account, but my goal was to use the find and replace function to find every instance of these phrases throughout the entire doc and remove them.

Reason I’d like a faster way is bc todays project consisted of over 1000 accts so lots of manual deleting of text.

I tried a Cntrl+h and then entered %=== and then replaced with “ “ (blank space)

And it just removed the ===